# Looping from 1 to 12 starting from any number between these

Tags: php, logic

I need to get a list of numbers starting from the current month to backwards 11 months.

I tried -

```
for($m=0;$m<12;$m++) {
echo date('m', strtotime("-$m months"));
}
```

but there is a bug/issue with this approach as strtotime returns duplicate months. e.g. for today's date it returns March twice. I want to use mktime function now and pass the $m as the month param. How do I get a list like this ... current month number is 4 so the list becomes ....

```
4, 3, 2, 1, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5.
```

How do I achieve this?

This is what I am trying to be able to achieve.

```
Apr 2015
Mar 2015
Feb 2015
Jan 2015
Dec 2014
Nov 2014
Oct 2014
Sep 2014
Aug 2014
Jul 2014
Jun 2014
May 2014
```

UPDATE

My php version is 5.2 and "today's" date is 2015-04-30.

Update 2-

I don't understand how is this question duplicate of the linked question (linked by John Conde. You need a holiday mate to get your brain some rest.). I have taken a look at the question and that doesn't resolve the issue I have.

Comment: Use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) objects ?

Comment: your loop gives me the correct series of numbers for todays date (may 1st)

Comment: No - it doesnt. it gives march twice. Todays date here is 30/04/2015

Comment: Turns out that was the clue - just start from the first day of the month.

Comment: Sorry @TigerTiger, I'm voting to leave this closed too. It is a duplicate of the other one. You need to alter the accepted answer *very* slightly, but it's still not different enough to be a completely different question.

Comment: @Mike - can you post your alteration suggestion as answer to this question? I will find out then if you guys are right.

Comment: @TigerTiger When a question is closed no new answers can be posted.

Comment: @TigerTiger I looked at the other answer and I see that the accepted answer is actually wrong. Instead look at John Conde's answer.

Comment: @TigerTiger Also, you should **really** think about updating your PHP. 5.2 has been past it's end of life [for more than 4 years now](http://php.net/eol.php).

Comment: no we cant upgrade php. if anyone has answer please post

Comment: @TigerTiger *I have taken a look at the question* So and why shouldn't your question be a dupe of the other one? What is the difference, what makes your question different from the dupe?! Explain to us why it shouldn't be a dupe!

Comment: Also FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/7898504  3 other users also agreed to leave the question closed and that it is not different from the dupe!

Comment: @Rizier123 - you show me how my question is duplicate of the linked question. I have already added my comments below and the answer there doesn't resolve my problem. if you guys have some privileges here that doesn't mean you are right and keep going marking as duplicate. If you can't answer simple tell me you are incapable. I disagree that it is a duplicate.

Comment: @TigerTiger The problem is that you go with `strtotime()` from today, which is the 30 April. So if you iteration over February which doesn't have 30 days you will run into exactly this problem which you have now! So you might want to take a look at the answer from John Conde in the dupe. *first day of this month* <- There is a reason why he used this in his code!

Comment: @TigerTiger i dont see why you are complaining - you have a functioning answer already. your question doesn't NEED to be open any longer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that February has 28 or 29 days.
My solution is far from being bullet proof but it works for what you need:

```
for($m=0;$m< 12;$m++) {
    $days = $m * 31;
    echo date('M Y', strtotime("-$days days"))."\n";
}
```

---

Output:

```
Apr 2015
Mar 2015
Feb 2015
Jan 2015
Dec 2014
Nov 2014
Oct 2014
Sep 2014
Aug 2014
Jul 2014
Jun 2014
May 2014
```

---

Demo:

http://ideone.com/Pl9CRP

---

For more information, please visit PHP.net regarding the `date()` function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: The above doesn't return Apr month for 1st of May .... you can try changing to this date('M Y', strtotime("-$days days", strtotime('2015-05-01'))); so it only works for today's date (30/04/2015)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Just force it to check from the start of the month, rather than the current day of the month:

```
  $months = array();
  for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    $months[] = date("M Y", strtotime(date('Y-m-01') . " -$i months"));
  }
  print_r($months);
```

Gives the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Apr 2015
    [1] => Mar 2015
    [2] => Feb 2015
    [3] => Jan 2015
    [4] => Dec 2014
    [5] => Nov 2014
    [6] => Oct 2014
    [7] => Sep 2014
    [8] => Aug 2014
    [9] => Jul 2014
    [10] => Jun 2014
    [11] => May 2014
)
```

Comment: You are passing this "2015-04-01 -1 months, 2015-04-01 -2 months, 2015-04-01 -3 months" to strtotime. Is that a valid format??

Comment: Seems to be. It gives you the correct results

Comment: You can test it by changing `-01` to `-30` and see that it starts failing as per your original question.